# Datepicker only is shown once in a dialog jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I created a dialog using jquery-ui, and inside it I have a datepicker. First time I create the dialog and when the input which has datepicker, has the focus, the datepicker shows correctly, but if I close the dialog and create it again, although the input which has the datepicker, has the focus, the datepicker doesn't show.

I found other similar questions but I can't to resolve this problem.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/VM4Hq/6/) is the code I'm, using (jsfiddle)

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btnDialog" />

$(function() {
    $('#btnDialog').on('click',function() {        
        var formContent = '<form> <fieldset>' +
          '<label for="name">Date (dd.mm.yyyy)</label>' +
          '<input type="text" id="myDate" />' +
          '</fieldset> </form>';
        $('<div id="myDialog" title="Text Dialog">' + formContent + '</div>').dialog();
        var options = eval('({dateFormat: \'dd.mm.yy\', changeYear: true,numberOfMonths: 1, firstDay: 1})');
        $("#myDate").datepicker(options);
    });    
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. The fiddle works fine.

Comment: When you close dialog and then click on the button, there's no datepicker anymore.

Comment: @Askanison4 the problem is that when I close the dialog and I push the button again, and I click out of the input and I click on the input again, the datepicker doesn't show.

Comment: @tilda and how can I create it again? I thought that the call $("#myDate").datepicker(options); create it if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**
Please check if the below code is fine for you. you need to append it to body.

**NOTE:**
if you don't want to retain the previous content then do as below:

```
$("#myDate").datepicker().val("").focus();
```

check the below code if it helps:

**jsfiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/VM4Hq/12/**

**html:**

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btnDialog" />
```

**jquery:**

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('#btnDialog').on('click', function() {
        i++;
        if (i === 1) {
            var formContent = '<form> <fieldset>' +
                    '<label for="name">Date (dd.mm.yyyy)</label>' +
                    '<input type="text" id="myDate" />' +
                    '</fieldset> </form>';
            $('<div id="myDialog" title="Text Dialog">' + formContent + '</div>').appendTo("body");
        }
        $("#myDialog").dialog();
        $("#myDate").datepicker().focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know this solution, but the html file (really, the jsp file) is shared for different pages and I wouldn't want to put the form on it, this is why I create the form using a string. Could it be do with it?

Comment: you want to create the form dynamically??

Comment: Yes, well... I don't want to create the form in the jsp, because although it's not displaying it's there and I don't like that. If there's no other solution this is what I'll do, but if is there another method... Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution I changed the id attribute to class attribute when creating the dynamic form as you did before. But still there are n number of ways this code can be made to work, I would prefer this.

If you don't want to use counters and to add some extra code in your script then here,

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btnDialog" />

$(function() {
    $('#btnDialog').on('click',function() {        
        var formContent = '<form> <fieldset>' +
          '<label for="name">Date (dd.mm.yyyy)</label>' +
          '<input type="text" id="myid" class="myDate" />' +
          '</fieldset> </form>';
        $('<div id="myDialog" title="Text Dialog">' + formContent + '</div>').dialog();
        var options = eval('({dateFormat: \'dd.mm.yy\', changeYear: true,numberOfMonths: 1, firstDay: 1})');
        $(".myDate").datepicker(options);
        $("input").blur();
    });    
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VM4Hq/14/)

This code will do that for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: jsfiddle demo doesn't work ??
if you don't write counter. multiple forms are added on each click. that was the reason it was not working for him as id's cant be multiple. id is unique. so only it was working on first click

Comment: I dont see calendar popping up ??

Comment: well i dont know what exactly is the problem you are facing..but it is working for me..i can able to open and close the modal dialog and the calendar pop up evertime i do that..which browser are you using..i have tested in Firefox..report me the bug if u r on a different browser..i updated my code to loose focus on click of the button..thanks..